# Can we customize the default style of hub or panorama app

Tags: windows-phone-8, panorama-control

[image]

I am trying to customize the hub or panorama style in WP8. Can I make Screen 1 by customizing the default hub or panorama style? I am having trouble in changing the default Screen 2 style. Is it possible, and how?

Comment: yep, by using pivot control

Comment: any code snippet .. or guide line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would just create a custom header

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ItemHeaderCustomStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">          
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="44"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-12,24,30,0"/>
            <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="-35"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>   
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <phone:Pivot>                    
            <phone:PivotItem>
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="main" Style="{StaticResource ItemHeaderCustomStyle}"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header> 
                <StackPanel/>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem>
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="view" Style="{StaticResource ItemHeaderCustomStyle}"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header> 
                <StackPanel/>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem >
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="features" Style="{StaticResource ItemHeaderCustomStyle}"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <StackPanel/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
    </Grid>
```